# Effect on SEO based on Position of meta tag on a page

Tags: html, seo

This could be the stupidest question ever, but I have to ask to be 100% sure.

We are changing our product page on our e-commerce website and this question came up (don't ask how)

In our current page the meta tags are right at the very top of the page, while in our new page they are after the css and JavaScript files import.

The question is will this be of any difference to the SEO? I mean will search engine have any bearing on the position of meta tag on a page. They are still in the head tag of html, just that there postion has changed.

Any suggestion/response will be very helpful.

Regards

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put meta tag tags anywhere in head tag, but first meta tags and then css files are more effective than first css files and then meta tags.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. I will anyways move them at the top.

Comment: The difference is marginal at best, so don't spend hours on it I'd say. But yeah, if it's an easy fix it would be best to put it at the very top (just after the charset and title)

Comment: Yeah the fix is easy. But when they asked me this question I thought I should see if there is any difference at all or not.